# skip steps in tour linkedin hopscotch

Tags: angularjs, linkedin-api

I'm using linkedin hopscotch to create a tour in an Angular app, in this app depending of some conditions I need to skip the tour to an specific step.

so I have something like this:

```
hopscotch.registerHelper("skipToStep", function(stepIdx) {
 console.log(hopscotch.getCurrStepNum());
 console.log(hopscotch.getState());
 hopscotch.showStep(stepIdx);
 console.log(hopscotch.getCurrStepNum());
 console.log(hopscotch.getState());
});
```

and then I put the callback inside the step in the tour

```
steps[1].onNext = ["skipToStep", 5]
```

the output of the console when i click next in the step 1 is:

```
2
graphTour:1

5 
graphTour:5
```

but the step that appears is the step[2], does anyone know how is the proper way to skip to a specific step ???

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without registering the helper?

I would call the showStep directly in the onNext callback. Something like this:

```
toolsTour = {
  id: "graphTour", 
  steps: [
    {   title: "Home/Start",
        content: "Some text bla bla.",
        target: "someDiv",
        placement: "right" ,
        onNext: function() {
            hopscotch.showStep(5);      
        }
    },
    ...
```

It works fine for me.